# How to obtain debugged program module information through DTE in VisualStudio Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, envdte

I want to get the debugged program information in vs through Dte com interface.

I found the Module definition in the documentation, but I can't get the object from the DTE, can anyone guide me?

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5PrX.png)
```